# Data-aware controls are "empty" after closing, reopening datasets and TDatabase

Tags: database, delphi, bde

I recently updated an old Delphi project to separate the creation of its data module and opening of that module's `TDatabase`, `TTable` and `TClientDataSet` components from the creation and showing of the app's form. Now, the app can toggle on and off the data components of the app. This new capacity isn't critical of course, but is "nice to have." My tool chain is RS v21 (the marketing version 10.4.1).

Yet there's a problem: after closing and reopening the data components from the UI, data aware controls show no data. Tests show that the underlying tables are open, can be navigated, and field values can be retrieved programmatically.

I've also established that resetting a data aware component's `DataSource` restores its display of underlying field data.

NB: data aware controls' `DataSource` are set at design time and, at run time after closing and reopening data tables, are not `nil`.

I conclude that resetting `DataSource` has a side effect -- probably tickling the `DataLink` within.

You can imagine I would like a means to obviate the need to reset a whole bunch of `DataSource`s. The easy hopes that `TDataSet` methods like `Refresh` all fail. ;-)

A sketch of the coding inside the app's form looks like this -- to open:

```
dm:=Tdm.Create(nil);
dm.OpenDatabase;
dm.OpenDataTables;
```

And closing is the reverse:

```
dm.CloseDataTables;
dm.CloseDatabase;
dm.Free;
dm:=nil;
```

In the database `Tdm`: In design, the datasets are not active, and the database is not connected. `Tdm.OpenDatabase` envokes Open on the TDatabase; `Tdm.OpenDataTables` runs through the needed tables using their `Open` method. `Tdm.CloseDatabase` and `Tdm.CloseDataTables` are symmetrical.

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: It is more common to leave the connections inactive in the data module but let it be auto created and disposed of normally. You don't save much not auto-creating it at application launch. You do save a lot by not opening / activating the various things on the data module until needed.

Comment: You're using the datamodule incorrectly. It should be in the autocreate list ahead of your main form, and should not be free'd. Freeing it clears all of the connections to the datamodule's controls, which is exactly what is causing the behavior you describe. Freeing the datamodule first frees all the components on it, which first disconnects all of the data-aware controls connected to it, which clears the DataSource property of all of those controls.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add a solution to the question itself. If you've solved the problem and want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.